# Reduce the width of a <div> block using css

Tags: css

This is the page I have created :

[image]

I want to reduce the width of the block which has the orange color as a background-color, without using a number in the property width, is there any other method to do that ?

I tried float:left; and it worked but it goes to the left I want the width to be detected automaticly due to the text lenght and in the center of the html page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want it to be centered, with an auto width, one option would be to treat it as an `inline` element.

```
display: inline;
```

or:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Assuming the parent element has `text-align: center`, this should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to add a wrapper element around the div:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">Vous avez acheté 6 pieces, le total à payer est : 200DH</div>
</div>
```

and then:

```
#inner {
    display: inline-block; /* for the background */
}

#outer {
    text-align: center; /* for centering */
}
```

http://cssdesk.com/Y8SB8

The wrapper is, of course, unnecessary if the div's parent already has `text-align: center`.